# Saving an Entity using json in Google App Engine NDB Datastore

Tags: json, google-app-engine, knockout.js, flask-wtforms

Hello Developers I am using Python Flask , Knockout.js and Google App Engine. Now I am making the basic program which is poster I am just posting some stuff using poster. But It seems that Google App Engine Datastore does not takes the values from `request.json['...']`
when form.validate_on_submit() is also in if condition of the view.

Here is my Flask View code

```
@app.route('/post/new',methods=['POST','GET'])
def post_it():
  form = CreatePost(request.form)
  use_db = ndb.Key(model.User, current_user.name)
  if **form.validate_on_submit()** and request.method=='POST':
    posting = model.Post(
        name = use_db,
        poster = request.json['post'],
        postbody = request.json['postbody'],
        posturl = request.json['posturl'],

      )
    try:
      posting.put()
      flash("Poster has been populated", category='info')
      return jsonify({ "post": request.json['post'],"postbody": request.json['postbody'], "posturl": request.json['posturl'] })
    except CapabilityDisabledError:
      flash('Error Occured while posting')
      return redirect(url_for('post_it'))
  return render_template('poster.html', form=form, use_db = use_db, post_db = post_db)

@app.route('/posts',methods=['GET'])
def all_posts():
  post_db = model.Post.query()
  return jsonify(post_db=post_db)
```

My poster.html code

```
    <form id="new_postform" action="{{ url_for('post_it') }}" data-bind="submit: addPost" class="navbar-form form-inline" method="post" >
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <fieldset>
          {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

             <div class="control-group">
                <p>Post</p>
                  <div class="controls">

                        <p>
                        {{ form.poster(id='post',class='form-control required ',placeholder="My Post", autocomplete=True , size=3,**{'data-bind': 'value: post'})}}</p>
                        {% if form.poster.errors %}
                        <ul class="errors">
                            {% for error in form.poster.errors %}
                            <li>{{ error }}</li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>


            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <p>postbody<p>
                  <div class="controls">


                        <p>{{ form.postbody(id='postbody',class='form-control required ',placeholder="Post Description", autocomplete=True , size=3, **{'data-bind': 'value: postbody'} )}}</p>

                    </div>


            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <p>post url</p>
                  <div class="controls">

                        <p>
                        {{ form.posturl(id='posturl',class='form-control required ',placeholder="My Post", autocomplete=True , size=3, **{'data-bind': 'value: posturl'} )}}</p>
                        {% if form.posturl.errors %}
                        <ul class="errors">
                            {% for error in form.posturl.errors %}
                            <li>{{ error }}</li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>


            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <br><input type="submit" id="postit"  name="postit" value"poster" class="btn btn-primary" /><br><br>

                    </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
    </form>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: posts, visible: posts().length > 0">
        <p data-bind="text: post"></p>
        <p data-bind="text: postbody"></p>
        <p data-bind="text: posturl"></p>
    </ul>
    <div class="controls">

    </div>




{% block tail_script %}
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap/js/jquery.validate.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap/js/additional-methods.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
 // This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI

function Post(data) {
    this.post = ko.observable(data.post);
    this.postbody = ko.observable(data.postbody);
    this.posturl = ko.observable(data.posturl);

}

function PostViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.posts = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.post = ko.observable();
    self.postbody = ko.observable();
    self.posturl = ko.observable();


    console.log(self.post)

    self.addPost = function() {
        self.save();
        self.post("");
        self.postbody("");
        self.posturl("");

    };

    $.getJSON('/posts', function(postModels) {
        var t = $.map(postModels.posts, function(item) {
            return new Post(item);
        });
        self.posts(t);
    });

    self.save = function() {
        return $.ajax({
            url: '/post/new',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                'post': self.post(),
                'postbody': self.postbody(),
                'posturl': self.posturl(),

            }),
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("Pushing to post array");
                self.posts.push(new Post({ post: data.post, postbody: data.postbody, posturl: data.posturl }));
                return;
            },
            error: function() {
                return console.log("Failed");
            }
        });
    };
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new PostViewModel());


</script>

{% endblock %}


{% endblock %}
```

is there any way to run form.validate_on_submit() with request.json['....'] , I am unable to figure where I am going wrong.

Comment: You might want to clean up a bit your code and have only the most important stuff.. start removing lines of code to isolate your problem and in the process you might also find the answer. It's hard to read between all those lines...

Comment: Lipis I have Edited the poster.html code with specific details